# Convert/access JSON file like DOM in JavaScript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to know how to convert or access a JSON file like DOM in Javascript without using jQuery.

For example, in this json

```
{"u1" : "a":1 ,"b":5 ,"c":8 }
```

how could I apply DOM to get output from this?

Comment: So, I know what all these words mean, but they don't really go together. What are you trying to do?

Comment: That is not valid JSON - the "u1" appears to be an attempt at an array perhaps? or an object wrapper needed?

Comment: i want to make json file and take a user input (like a search) where i match both so i want to try get output  from json file  to match with user input .

Comment: So if you type in `b` into a text box something will happen (like an alert) to show the value of 5?

Answer (score 0):

IF this is your desired structure:

```
var myobject = {"u1": {"a": 1,"b": 5, "c": 8  }};
alert(myobject.u1.a);
```